# JavaScript: List Unique Attributes with Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am listing items for sale on a site, and I'd like to have a sidebar to filter the items. So for each attribute, in the filter section I want to list each unique value, and show a count of how many of that value there are.

As a very simple example, in the snippet below, there are four cars listed, with data-attributes for the number of doors. To let people filter by number of doors, I need to show each option in a sidebar and let them check one.

The problem for me is that for some of the attributes, I don't know what values there will be in advance. So I need some way to loop through each item, record each unique value for that attribute, and also count up the instances of each value, and display that in the "Filter By" sidebar.

This is what that sidebar would look like in the example:

Doors:
[] 2 (2)
[] 4 (1)
[] 5 (1)

It looks like I may need to use .each() and .length(), but I'm having trouble putting this together. I have no trouble filtering out the items once the checkboxes are checked, but my problem is just listing out all of the filter options.

```html
<div class="items-list">
  <p class="item" data-doors="2">Ford Mustang</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="5">Nissan Versa</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="4">Honda Civic</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="2">Audi A5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets up an object with key/value pairs the key being the number of doors, the value being how many instances of them. Then it runs that object through an iteration which applies the key value pairs to a checkbox input.

```js
const createCheckboxes = (dataName) => {
  let refobj = {};
  $('.items-list .item').each(function() {
    let d = $(this).data(dataName);
    refobj[d] = refobj[d] ? refobj[d] + 1 : 1;
  });

  Object.entries(refobj).forEach(set => $('.inputs[data-group="' + dataName + '"]').append(getCheckbox(set, dataName)));

}

const getCheckbox = (data, keyname) => {
  const [key, value] = data;
  return `
<label>
<input type='checkbox' name='${keyname}[]' class='${keyname}' value='${key}' onclick='testinput(this)' /> ${key} (${value})
</label>`
}

const testinput = (el) => {
  console.log('input with class: ' + $(el).attr('class') + '  and value: ' + $(el).val() + ' and name: ' + $(el).attr('name') + ' clicked')
}
createCheckboxes('doors');
createCheckboxes('wheels');
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-list">
  <p class="item" data-doors="2" data-wheels="4">Ford Mustang</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="5" data-wheels="4">Nissan Versa</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="4" data-wheels="4">Honda Civic</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="2" data-wheels="4">Audi A5</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="1" data-wheels="3">Messerschmitt KR200</p>
</div>

<div class='inputs' data-group="doors">How many doors?</div>

<div class='inputs' data-group="wheels">How many wheels?</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working for me. If I wanted to run this for multiple attributes (e.g. Doors and Axels), how would I modify the middle section?

Comment: You can use the approach I followed, in case you want to handle multiple attributes. Create another object like `filterObj` and add other keys similarly to doors.

Comment: (of the JavaScript)

Comment: I encapsulated it into a function and showed an example.

Comment: I have a couple of questions, if you don't mind, and I don't understand your code well enough to modify it myself. First, the input value is returning "undefined[]". Secondly, I'd like to pass the attribute name (e.g. Doors, Wheels) into the input, as a class. Would you mind showing me how to do that?

Comment: Ok, sorry about the value, that's fixed. and the class is there now.  Also, I'd be happy to explain any code you don't understand. feel free to ask

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I just have to study a few things to fully understand what you've done, but I think that will be a good exercise. You've been a huge help though!

Answer (score 1):

The final `filterObj` (in the below code) holds what you are looking for.

```js
const list = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
//Converting HTMLNode list to Array.
const arrList = Array.from(list);

const filterObj = {};
arrList.map(el => {
    filterObj[el.dataset.doors] = filterObj[el.dataset.doors] 
    ? filterObj[el.dataset.doors] + 1 
    : 1;
});

console.log(filterObj);
```

```html
<div class="items-list">
  <p class="item" data-doors="2">Ford Mustang</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="5">Nissan Versa</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="4">Honda Civic</p>
  <p class="item" data-doors="2">Audi A5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the other answer first and it worked for me, but this is also much appreciated!